# Создание уникальных значений для slug

Tags: python, django

есть Django-код, в нем имеется поле slug и его заполнение нужно сделать уникальным. Чтобы когда пользователь его заполнял и оно совпадало с тем который имеется выводилось что такой уже есть

```
models.py
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Course(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='course_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('course-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

```
forms.py
```

```
from django import forms
from .models import Course

class CreateCourse(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateCourse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['slug'].label = 'Название URL'
        self.fields['title'].label = 'Название курса'
        self.fields['description'].label = 'Описание курса'
        self.fields['img'].label = 'Изображение профиля'

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['slug', 'title', 'description', 'img']
```

```
views.py
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Course
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView
)
from .forms import CreateCourse

class HomePage(ListView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'courses/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'courses'
    ordering = ['-id']

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(HomePage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['title'] = 'Главная страница сайта'
        return ctx


class CourseDetailPage(DetailView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'courses/course-detail.html'

def create_course(reguest):
    if reguest.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateCourse(reguest.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            slug = form.cleaned_data['slug']
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            img = form.cleaned_data['img']
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = CreateCourse()

    return render(reguest, 'courses/course_form.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Добавление курса'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```